# Unable to output file names from directory in PHP

Tags: php, glob

I am using the following PHP script to output filenames from a directory

```
$num_rec_per_page=5;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
$start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 
$memefiles = array(glob("*.jpeg"));
for ($i=$start_from;$i<=$start_from+5;$i++) {
echo $memefiles[$i];
}
```

However it just echoes Array and not the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$memefiles = array(glob("*.jpeg"));
```

You're wrapping an array in another array for some reason.

Do this instead.

```
$memefiles = glob("*.jpeg");
```